# How to print filenames to a new file with a specific format using awk?

Tags: macos, awk

I'm trying to print a list of all jpg files in a directory to a new .txt file.

The output format in that .txt file should look like that:

```
<img src="filename.jpg">
```

Currently, I have this command:

```
ls -al *.jpg | awk ‘{print”<img src=”$9">"}' > list_of_files.txt
```

But it doesn't work. What would be the right command to get the right formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need awk or any other external tool for this, the shell can do it by itself:

```
printf '<img src="%s">\n' *.jpg > list_of_files.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

One in awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)                       # loop all argument files
        printf "<img src=\"%s\">\n", ARGV[i]  # output as requested
    exit                                      # never touch any files
}' *.jpg
```

Output sample:

```
<img src="foo.jpg">
<img src="bar.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -A1 *.jpg | awk '{print "<img src=\""$0"\">"}' > list_of_files.txt
```

Safe version (in case to have something like `rm -rf .. .jpg` in your files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *; do
  if [[ "$f" == *.jpg ]]; then
    echo "<img src=\""$f"\">" >> list_of_files.txt
  fi
done
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for the standard advice not to parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: `for f in *; do
  if [[ "$f" == *.jpg ]]` = `for f in *.jpg` and that echo leaves the file name exposed to the shell for globbing, etc. as it takes the `$f` out of the quotes but you don't need a loop at all - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549869/1745001).